# Problem in creating ScrollViewer UserControl in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I want to create a `MyScrollViewer` control with customized style.
I have created a `UserControl` for `ScrollViewer` (we cant able create a `CustomControl` because `ScrollViewer` From `System.Windows.Controls` is a sealed class), and in `UserControl`s resources I have added an style for `ScrollViewer` (Custom Style).

In Codebehind I have created a property `Content` which overrides the `Content` of base class(i.e. `UserControl`).

CodeBehind:

```
 public partial class ScrollViewer : UserControl
    {
        private System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer _scrollViewer;
        public ScrollViewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           // DataContext = this;
             _scrollViewer = new System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer();
        }

        public new object Content
        {
            get { return _scrollViewer; }
            set
            {
                _scrollViewer.Content = value;
                base.Content = _scrollViewer;
            }
        }
}
```

But problem with this code is that I am not able to get `Control`s inside `ScrollViewer` at runtime. Suppose I have a `TextBox` inside `ScrollViewer`, I am not able to get that control. E.g.:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrDetail" >
   <StackPanel Margin="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
         <Label Name="lblLevel" Content="Level" Margin="2"  />
         <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" Name="txtLevel"                           IsEnabled="False" Text="System" />
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am not able to set text at runtime because I am getting `txtLevel` as `null`.

Comment: what's the reason that you need to create a usercontrol rather than create a style for the default scrollviewer?

Comment: @Xin we have created a control library, i want to add make my conrol in that, so that every one can use that control.

Comment: you can also share your style right? also i don't think a usercontrol can be styled.

Comment: I think @Xin makes a good point - if you're only styling the ScrollViewer then creating a new UserControl is unnecessarily complex.  Create a style for the standard ScrollViewer and share that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in custom control class and you will be able to find TextBlock from style.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
         this.textBlock = this.GetTemplateChild("YourTextBlockName") as TextBlock; }
```